# How do I select the elements inside of another in CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I have this HTML code as an example:

```
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bootstrap Example</h1> 
        <p>Just another crazy blog</p> 
    </div>

   <div class="container">
      <p>This is some text.</p> 
      <p>This is another text.</p> 
  </div>
```

I am trying to style the jumbotron using this code:

```
.jumbotron h1, p{
  color: #FAE3F2;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;

}
```

The problem is that when I apply these changes, they also affect the paragraph inside the container and I can't understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.jumbotron h1, .jumbotron p{
  color: #FAE3F2;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;

}
```

The `,` separates whole expressions, so `.jumbotron` doesn't carry over to the second one.

Comment: Thx a lot, it actually worked. I was thinking to try this a bit different, but I seemed a bit rendundant. Guess is the only way after all.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the selectors with this one:

```
.jumbotron h1, .jumbotron p {...}
```

Having your selector without `.jumbotron p {..}` means that all the `p` elements will be selected.